# In Rails application how do I implement IdentityServer4 Client (Hybrid flow) and have user authentication and have ecured APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, identityserver4, openid-connect, openid

I have Ruby on Rails application for which the current authentication mechanism is Devise. Both frontend and backend are in Rails i.e we are using ERB/SLIM files. The current version of Rails is 4.2. We need to implement OAuth+OpenID for it.
The (SSO)Single Sign-On server is based on IdentityServer4. We are using Hybrid flow and hence receiving the tokens once the login is successful.

I am successfully able to sign in via SSO and land on my Rails endpoint where I am getting access_token.

**I want to what is the ideal/standard way to connect to my Rails APIs via Rails frontend(erb/slim) post successful login of user and receiving access_token i.e.**

1. **Shall I use the access_token and bypass the Devise login and communicate between frontend & backend via devise token** 
   OR
2. **Shall I use the access_token for every subsequent request and authenticate the user based on access_token.**

**Also access_token comes with an expiry, so shall I validate the access_token against SSO server for each request or validate the access_token only once an hour or so (I can store the access_token from SSO in DB and validate user request against it and after specified time validate with SSO).**

I have went through many blogs and youtube videos but they end up once I receive the access_token. I want to know the flow after we receive the access_token i.e. how to use them